# How to call a method with non reactive arguments with .map returning Mono

Tags: spring-webflux, reactive

```
protected Flux<ProspectContact> transformAndCallUpdateAPI(String eventHubMessage) {
    Mono.justOrEmpty(eventHubMessage)
            .map(this::parser)
            .map(this::parseToRequest) //this return Mono<ServiceRequest<ModelClass>>
            .map(updateMethod) //this method has 
       public Prospect updateProspectByContact(ServiceRequest<ModelClass> test) 
    )
}
```

How do I call updateMethod which has ServiceRequest as argument but .map(this::parseToRequest) returns Mono<ServiceRequest<ModelClass>>.

How to convert Mono<ServiceRequest<ModelClass>> to <erviceRequest<ModelClass> to call updateMethod. I do not want to use block() as it might create performance problems

Tried extracting ServiceRequest<ModelClass> from Mono<>, but nothing is working for me that I know of

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flatMap](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) for that.

flatMap get and call the publisher (Mono or Flux) provided by input function, and extract its value(s) to the downstream flow. Here is an example:

```java
// Returns a reactive type from a simple type
public <T> Mono<String> toString(T value) { 
    return Mono.justOrEmpty(value)
               .map(Object::toString);
}

Flux<Integer> countdown = Flux.just(3, 2, 1, 0);
// Transform each value, and prevent nesting of reactive types using flatMap
Flux<String> txtCountdown = countdown.flatMap(n -> toString(n));
```